# Is there a way to invoke the Xenon Flash for Windows Phones?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I've seen source code that's used to invoke the camera's LED light and this is used in a lot of flashlight apps on the store, however is there a way to programmatically invoke the Xenon lamps on the newer Nokia Windows Phones? I don't need it to be turned on constantly as I'm sure that'd cause the lamp to burn out. A simple example would be pressing a button and the flash gets invoked. If it's possible to access the LED flash through the camera API, is it possible to do the same with xenon flash through the same API's?

Comment: what happens when you try to call the flash on a phone where it's Xenon based? what else have you tried?

Comment: It just invokes the LED flash. There doesn't seem to be any specific API's or calls to invoke the Xenon flash, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the Windows Phone 8 camera APIs and trying a few apps in the store, it doesn't look like it's possible to access the Xenon flash equipped handset (eg. Nokia Lumia 1020).

When the flash is invoked on the Lumia 1020, the LED flash/light comes on instead. This could be for a few reasons...

1. So existing/future flash light apps don't burn out or damage the Xenon flash.
2. Only Nokia phones feature a Xenon flash, but Nokia cannot add new APIs to WP8 as they're an OEM - they don't control the OS.

Currently, the only way the Xenon flash is activated is through the standard picture taking process.

Comment: You actually gave me an idea for how to invoke the Xenon Flash. Older flashlight apps worked by invoking the camera API's as well while newer flash light apps work by calling something from System.Reflections. For Nokia devices, as long as the flash is set to always on, it will use the Xenon Flash. I'm going to try to create a custom camera app, but hide the camera feed and have a single button take pictures with flash always enabled. I'll see if I can invoke the flash that way.

Comment: Good idea, it'll be interesting to see if it gets approved on the store!